# Avoid declaration of if regex statements while using Exported Resources in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Avoid to add a host manually

```
class::define {  [
    'host1.domain',
    'host2.domain'
  ]:
    attribute  => 'hello',
    attribute2 => 'world'
}

class::define {  [
    'host3.domaintwo',
    'host4.domaintwo'
  ]:
    attribute  => 'apple',
    attribute2 => 'orange'
}
```

by using exported resources:

```
if $fqdn =~ /^.*\.domain$/ {
  @@class::define { $fqdn:
    attribute  => 'hello',
    attribute2 => 'world',
    tag => 'test'
  }
}

if $fqdn =~ /^.*\.domaintwo$/ {
  @@class::define { $fqdn:
    attribute  => 'apple',
    attribute2 => 'orange',
    tag => 'test2'
  }
}

Class::define <<| tag == 'test' and tag == 'test2' |>>
```

works as expected.

**Question**

Could the if statements be omitted to get the same outcome?

Comment: It is thoroughly unclear what you are asking. You might want to break this up into several questions. What is the minimal use case that you need to get working but cannot?

Comment: @FelixFrank I will create another question this evening and extend this one.

Comment: @FelixFrank The question has been updated and a [new one](http://serverfault.com/questions/669706/is-it-possible-to-declare-exported-resources-as-an-attribute-instead-of-a-type-i) has been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making the exports unconditional, you will provoke a collision, because the manifest now declares the exported resource

```
Class::Define[$fqdn]
```

twice (with different attributes).

You can avoid this by allowing to pass the FQDN as an attribute value, instead of expecting it to be the resource title.

```
@@class::other_define {
    "hello-$fqdn":
        fqdn => $fqdn,
        attribute  => 'hello',
        attribute2 => 'world',
        tag => 'test';
    "fruit-$fqdn":
        fqdn => $fqdn,
        attribute  => 'apple',
        attribute2 => 'orange',
        tag => 'test2';
}
```

Just make sure to still **use** the `fqdn` fact in resource titles, so that the exports from distinct agents will not collide.

As an aside, I'm not sure why you pick distinct tags, and why importing only resources that have *both* tags works "as expected". In fact, I'd expect that to import nothing.